# What is the smallest awk program to print a section of a configuration file?

Tags: awk

First off, I know that normal conf files that follow this format (I don't know what its called) usually have an empty line separating sections, which makes this problem a lot easier. But I was wondering if there was a small and clean way to print only section2 of the following file in awk (called test.conf):

```
[section1]    
a = 1         
b = 2         
[section2]    
c = 3         
d = 4         
[section3]    
e = 5         
d = 6
```

My first guess failed:

```
bash-3.2$ awk '/^\[section2\]$/,/^\[/' test.conf
[section2]
```

because the same line matches both the start and end range delimiters. I have a feeling there is a better way to do this than setting some variable when you get to section2 and then turning it off when you get to the next section. Anybody knows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### AWK Solution

An [INI file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file#Order_of_sections_and_properties) doesn't usually guarantee the order of its sections, so the following is somewhat fragile because it's order-dependent. However, it is extremely short and works with your defined corpus.

```
$ gawk '/section3/ {exit}; /section2/,/section3/ {print}' /tmp/foo.ini
[section2]
c=3
d=4
```

### Alternatives

- Use sed to delete lines. Short and not order-dependent, but perhaps a bit cryptic.

  ```
  $ sed -n '/section2/, /^\[/ { /section[^2]/d; p }' /tmp/foo.ini
  [section2]
  c=3
  d=4
  ```
- Use Perl's flip-flop operator. Extremely flexible.

  ```
  $ perl -ne 'push(@lines, $_) if /section2/.../section3/;
              END {pop @lines; print @lines}' /tmp/foo.ini
  [section2]
  c=3
  d=4
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I don't know what the flip-flop operator is, but I'm going to learn more about it.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it

```
awk '/\[section2\]/,/\[section3\]/{if ($0 !~ /\[section3\]/) print}' test.conf
```

or easier with sed

```
sed -n '/\[section2\]/,/\[section3\]/{/\[section3\]/!p}' test.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
awk -vRS=[ /section2/ test.conf
```

The result is not perfect:

```
section2]    
c = 3         
d = 4
```

---

Another command:

```
awk -vRS=[ '/section2/{print RS$0}' test.conf
```

Comment: Please use *printf* instead of *print* to avoid an extraneous newline at the end of the record. However, +1 for the effective use of RS to find the section.

Comment: This is gawk solution, not all awk support this type of RS

Comment: Adding `-F "section2]"` and doing `{print $2}`will get rid of the section header, but there will be blank lines before and after the useful output.

Comment: @Jotne, this is a simple one-character `RS`, should be pretty well supported, for what I know.
Edit: you meant the -v option, okay.

Answer (score 1):

Not the shortest one, but at least the section ordering doesn't break it:

```
$ awk '/^\[section2/ {p=1; next}; /^\[/ {p=0}; p'  test.conf
c = 3         
d = 4
```

And works with every awk.

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk`

```
awk '/section3/ {exit} /section2/ {f=1} f' /tmp/foo.ini
```